# Error on installing ruby 2.4.5 on Solaris 10

Tags: ruby, installation, solaris-10

I am trying to build ruby 2.4.5 from source on Solaris 10 machine. When I run the  ./configure command, it gives the below error:

```
checking for off_t... yes
checking char bit... 8
checking size of int... 0
checking size of short... 0
checking size of long... 0
checking size of long long... configure: error: in `/test/ruby-2.4.5/objdir':
configure: error: cannot compute sizeof (long long)
See `config.log' for more details
```

On checking the config.log, I see the below error:

```
configure:12038: result: 0
configure:12133: checking size of long long
configure:12138: gcc -o conftest  -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -std=gnu99   -fstack-protector conftest.c -lsocket -ldl -lcrypt -lm  >&5
configure:12138: $? = 0
configure:12138: ./conftest
ld.so.1: conftest: fatal: libssp.so.0: open failed: No such file or directory
../configure: line 2064:  9111 Killed                  ./conftest$ac_exeext
configure:12138: $? = 137
configure: program exited with status 137
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
```

From the config.log, I understand that libssp.so.0 is missing but I cant find this on my Solaris 10 machine nor find any specific help on this issue. Can somebody help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Install [libssp0](https://www.opencsw.org/packages/libssp0/):

```
pkgadd -d http://get.opencsw.org/now
/opt/csw/bin/pkgutil -U
/opt/csw/bin/pkgutil -y -i libssp0 
/usr/sbin/pkgchk -L CSWlibssp0 # list files
```

Alternatively, install [gcc4core](https://www.opencsw.org/packages/gcc4core/) and it will be installed automatically as a dependency:

```
pkgadd -d http://get.opencsw.org/now
/opt/csw/bin/pkgutil -U
/opt/csw/bin/pkgutil -y -i gcc4core 
/usr/sbin/pkgchk -L CSWgcc4core # list files
```

Comment: Unfortunately my machine is behind a firewall and I cannot install this way. Any other way to download and install libssp0?

Comment: Yes, there is an option to [download packages](https://www.opencsw.org/community/questions/92/installing-without-direct-internet-access) on a secondary machine running Solaris and export them for another server. You can also [setup an internal mirror](https://www.opencsw.org/manual/for-administrators/mirror-setup.html). You can also [grab the pkg.gz](http://mirror.opencsw.org/opencsw/allpkgs/) directly if you know the right version.